# Android PreferenceActivity to create a MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE preference across applications

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I have multiple applications that share certain data through preferences. Each app sets its preferences through a PreferenceActitivity (from xml). Two questions:

How do I use/edit preferences created by one app in another app. If I figure out how to create MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE preferences using PreferenceActivity that will solve the problem.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
          <String referring to another package´s prefs>, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) prefs
          .getAll();


        String str = map.toString();
        tv.setText(str);
```

Above code returns {}

- Second, how do I use addPreferencesFromIntent(i) -- I am getting a NullPointerException even though the intent is not Null.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Best,
Sameer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access preferences from another app in a secure way set the same [android:sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) in the Manifest. This will allow you to access preferences & files in MODE_PRIVATE (or secure) manner.

After much time spent, we realized this alone will not work and one needs to create a package context of the first app to access files in the second app:

```
try {
            Context c = createPackageContext(com.app.first, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(
                    "com.app.first_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

A big thank you to @CommonsWare and Karthik Shanmugam for their help!

Comment: But you cannot add sharedUserId if the apps are already live... It messes a lot of things up. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The downside of this solution is that second application must assume that the first application is installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11803585/722603